# Role is not getting added to member

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have some code that detects when someone enters the command `role` and gives them the role with the name of the first argument passed to the command (`args[0]`). For example, the bot would try to detect something like `!role nameOfTheRole`, which would give the user the role with the name `nameOfTheRole`.

However, the code is not working and I'm not sure why. Here is what I have mnaged to get so far:

```js
var cmdmap = {
    role: gimmerole
}

function gimmerole(member, args, message) {
    var memb = message.member() //<------- ERROR

    const role = memb.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == args[0])
    memb.roles.add(role)
}

client.on('message', (msg) => {
    var cont   = msg.content,
        author = msg.member,
        chan   = msg.channel,
        guild  = msg.guild

    if (author.id != client.user.id && cont.startsWith(config.prefix)) {

        var invoke = cont.split(' ')[0].substr(config.prefix.length),
            args   = cont.split(' ').slice(1)

        console.log(invoke, args)
        if (invoke in cmdmap) {
            cmdmap[invoke](msg, args)
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: Against popular belief `does not work` is not sufficient information to provide to receive help. What's the actual (unwanted) behavior? Do you get any errors? What's your relevant code that might be causing the issue - How's `memb` defined?

Comment: var memb = member

Comment: Please do not add messages like *idk why please help me cause im dumb* as it will not help you. It will end up making your question get closed. I'd advise removing all of the unnecessary messages and adding more detail as to what the issue actually is.

Comment: I just edited your post, but I'd advise you add any extra details or correct anything I added that is incorrect.

Comment: Please improve the title of your question and take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few modifications to your code:

- I changed the line `function gimmerole(member, args, message) {` to `function gimmerole(message, args) {`, as in the line `cmdmap[invoke](msg, args);`, you are calling it with the message object and the arguments, so the message was getting assigned to `member` instead and `message` would have been `undefined`.
- I changed `message.member()` to `message.member`, as `member` is a property of `message`, not a method.
- I also changed the code that parses the message and splits it into a command and arguments so that it's a lot cleaner.
- Added a sanity check (`` if (!role) return console.log(`The role "${args[0]}" does not exist`); ``) to make the bot log to the console if the role does not exist.
- Changed `args[0]` to `args.join(' ')` to enable roles with spaces to be specified.

```js
var cmdmap = {
    role: gimmerole
};

function gimmerole(message, args) {
    const member = message.member;

    const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === args.join(' '));
    if (!role) return console.log(`The role "${args.join(' ')}" does not exist`);

    member.roles.add(role);
}

client.on('message', (msg) => {
    var cont   = msg.content,
        author = msg.member,
        chan   = msg.channel,
        guild  = msg.guild;

    if (author.id !== client.user.id && cont.startsWith(config.prefix)) {

        const [invoke, ...args] = cont.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');

        console.log(invoke, args);
        if (invoke in cmdmap) {
            cmdmap[invoke](msg, args);
        }
    }

})
```

There is the [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/) that you can use if you want something to follow along with. It is really helpful and detailed.

Comment: this is not working but it is not giving errors

Comment: or you just edited it

Comment: isnt working and no errors in console

Comment: i just dont get the role

Comment: @HELPME OK, I'm looking into it. Please do not spam comments.

Comment: @HELPME It worked fine for me. Are you sure the bot has sufficient permissions to give you the role?

Comment: yes the bot has admin perm and is over Owner

Comment: @HELPME I have made some modifications. Please try the new code.

Comment: One Question could we talk in Discord??? and it shows the role id in console but wont give it to me

Comment: @HELPME Yeah, it would probably be better if we talked in Discord. Send the invite link here then delete it after I join to prevent others from joining.

Comment: https://discord.gg/czQVgh3g

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed you're improperly trying to find a role. In order to get a full roles collection, you will need to use the `cache` method of `message.guild.roles`, resulting in the line:

```
const roleObject = memb.guild.roles.cache.find(...);
```

Comment: Error : Cannot read property 'member' of undefined,

code : var memb = message.member()

Comment: I don't exactly get your code. You're trying to make a function that gives someone a role, but that function does not have a callback nor is it really an event of some sort. How is this going to be executed?

Comment: updated it the post

Comment: hi are you still there because i rly need help rn

Answer (score 0):

var cmdmap = {

```
role: gimmerole
```

};

function gimmerole(message, args) {

```
const member = message.member;

const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === args.join(' '));
if (!role) return console.log(`The role "${args.join(' ')}" does not exist`);

member.roles.add(role);
```

}

client.on('message', (msg) => {

```
var cont   = msg.content,
    author = msg.member,
    chan   = msg.channel,
    guild  = msg.guild;

if (author.id !== client.user.id && cont.startsWith(config.prefix)) {

    const [invoke, ...args] = cont.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');

    console.log(invoke, args);
    if (invoke in cmdmap) {
        cmdmap[invoke](msg, args);
    }
}
```

}

- Credits to Deamon Beast